# How to do multiple integral numerically?

Tags: numerical-integration

I cannot calculate the following type of integrals numerically :

$\int_0^1 dy \int_0^y f(x) dx $

$f(x)$ can be a complicated function. The problem is due to the fact that the upper limit of one of the integrals is not a number. Can anyone suggest how to compute it. Many thanks!

**Edit :** Actually my aim is to calculate a residue. I didn't want to bother you with these long expressions. Here is what I wish to compute (numerically at least).

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{\int_0^x \text{P}(w) S(w) \, dw}{\text{P}(x)},\left\{x,\frac{1}{\pi }\right\}\right)$$
where, 
$$\text{P}(\text{z}) \text{ := }\frac{1-\pi ^4 z^4}{z^3}$$
$$S(\text{z})\text{ := } \pi ~ A(z) F(z)-\pi ^2 B(z)+\frac{\pi  F'(z)}{2 (1-\pi  z)} $$
$$F(\text{z})\text{ :=}\int_0^z \frac{\int_0^y \pi  A(u) \text{P}(u) \, du}{\text{P}(y)} \, dy-\frac{3 \left(\log \left(\pi ^2 z^2+1\right)+\log (\pi  z+1)+\log (1-\pi  z)\right)}{64 \pi ^4}$$ 
$$A(\text{z})\text{ :=}\frac{\pi  z (\pi  z+2)+3}{4 z (\pi  z-1) (\pi  z+1) \left(\pi ^2 z^2+1\right)}$$
$$B(\text{z})\text{ :=}\frac{(\pi  z (\pi  z+2)+3) (\pi  z (\pi  z (\pi  z+1)+1)+5)}{16 (\pi  z-1) (\pi  z+1)^2 \left(\pi ^2 z^2+1\right)^2}$$

Comment: Can you give us an example of $y$, and possibly a reduced version of $f(x)$ as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/problem-with-nintegrate-in-nonlinearmodelfit

Comment: Also this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83335/how-to-solve-numerically-an-equation-which-contains-numerical-intergration

Comment: It's a [repeated integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatedIntegral.html); what you have is equivalent to $$\int_0^1 (1-x)f(x)\mathrm dx$$ That being said, and do forgive me for my bluntness, you've been quite vague as to the nature of your $f(x)$, and this makes it difficult to assist you. Methods that are efficient for one class fail spectacularly for another, so more elaboration is necessary.

Comment: You see, you should have included those expressions at the outset. It's gnarly now, but it should be amenable to some simplification.

Comment: You might get more help if you posted *Mathematica* code instead of TeX for your definitions.  Also, if you posted any errors or warnings you get, some site users might know what's wrong and be more likely to engage.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (assuming that `y` is not a complicated function, but it is easily generalized to that case):

```
f[x_?NumberQ]:=(*your function*)

I1[y_?NumberQ]:=NIntegrate[f[x],{x,0,y}]

I2=NIntegrate[I1[y],{y,0,1}]
```

As an example:

```
f[x_?NumberQ] := x;
I1[y_?NumberQ] := NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, y}];
NIntegrate[I1[y], {y, 0, 1}]
```

with the result:

> 0.166667

You can check with `Integrate` that theresult is correct.

The `_?NumberQ` in the definition of the functions mean that the function will be evaluated only if the input variable has a numerical value. [A link to its use.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html)

And [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/problem-with-nintegrate-in-nonlinearmodelfit) a link to a problem similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks @mattiav27 ! Can you suggest how to modify it for complicated functions. Actually my functions are really complicated. Your code works fine for simple functions, I have checked. I don't understand why it isn't working for complicated functions.

Comment: @pinu I need your function: edit you first post

Comment: @pinu: meanwhile you can take a look at this old question of mine: there are two nested numerical integrations with complicated functions http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56212/8822